# IE, XDomainRequest not always work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain, xdomainrequest

I am trying to do cross-domain on IE.

I used XDomainRequest, and implanted logging for all events (onerror, onload, onprogress and ontimeout) to monitor the progress.

It works sometime, but not always (one computer, IE9, same site, same request, 1 out of 3 or 4 works; another computer, IE8, maybe 1 out of 2 works). I didn't get any useful information from the logging, because there was nothing triggered.

I am very confused. Any debugging tool for IE? Why some time XDomainRequest just doesn't work?

Thanks a lot
coronin

Comment: Debug using IE's built-in JavaScript debugger (Hit F12 to open it), or using [Visual Web Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express) (which is free).

Comment: Hi gilly3, I tried F12, and there was nothing shown. I am checking Visual Web Developer now~~

Answer (score 20):

There are at least two significant bugs in the XDomainRequest object, one that affects IE8 and another that affects IE9.

**Issue 1 - Garbage Collection**

In Internet Explorer 8, the XDomainRequest object is incorrectly subject to garbage collection after send() has been called but not yet completed. The symptoms of this bug are the Developer Tools' network trace showing "Aborted" for the requests and none of the error, timeout, or success event handlers being called.

Typical AJAX code looks a bit like this:

```
function sendCrossDomainAjax(url, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
  xdr.open("get", url);
  xdr.onload = function() { successCallback(); }
  xdr.onerror = function() { errorCallback(); }
  xdr.send();
}
```

In this example, the variable containing XDomainRequest goes out of scope. If the user is unlucky, IE's Javascript garbage collector will run before send() asynchronously completes and the request will be aborted. Even though the XDomainRequest object can be captured into the OnLoad and OnError event handlers, IE will see that that entire object graph has no references to it and will garbage collect it. IE should be "pinning" the object until complete.

You'll notice quite a few other discussions on the internet mentioning that placing a setTimeout around the xdr.send(); call will somehow "solve" mysterious XDomainRequest failures. This is a kludge, and completely incorrect. All that's happening is that the XDomainRequest object is being "pinned" into the setTimeout closure and not subject to garbage collection as quickly. It doesn't solve the problem.

To correctly work around this issue, ensure the XDomainRequest is stored in a global variable until the request completes. For example:

```
var pendingXDR = [];

function removeXDR(xdr) {
  // indexOf isn't always supported, you can also use jQuery.inArray()
  var index = pendingXDR.indexOf(xdr);
  if (index >= 0) {
    pendingXDR.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

function sendCrossDomainAjax(url, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
  xdr.open("get", url);

  xdr.onload = function() {
    removeXDR(xdr);
    successCallback();
  }

  xdr.onerror = function() {
    removeXDR(xdr);
    errorCallback();
  }

  xdr.send();
  pendingXDR.push(xdr);
}
```

**Issue 2 - Missing OnProgress EventHandler**

This second issue is already known. Internet Explorer 9 introduced a regression in the XDomainRequest object where a missing (null) OnProgress event handler would cause the request to abort when it tries to report progress information.

For fast requests, IE9 never attempts to call the OnProgress event handler and the request succeeds. Certain conditions, such as when IE delays the request due to too many open connections, network latency, slow server responses, or large request or response payloads will cause IE9 to start to report progress information.

IE9 tries to call the event handler without first checking it exists, and the XDomainRequest object crashes and destroys itself internally.

To solve this issue, always ensure an event handler is attached to OnProgress. Given the bug, it's not a bad idea to defensively add event handlers to all of the object's events.

```
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
xdr.open("get", url);
xdr.onprogress = function() { };
// regsister other event handlers
```

**Other Issues**

I've seem reports that XDomainRequest can fail if the event handlers are registered before .open() is called. Again, defensively, it's not a bad idea to register them between the .open() and .send() calls. I haven't personally verified whether it's an actual bug.

If you run into an "Access Denied" error, it's because XDomainRequest doesn't allow mismatched URI schemes between the target and host page. In other words, try don't call an HTTP resource from an HTTPS page.

Beware most of the XDomainRequest libraries on the internet. I looked at most of the popular ones, such as the various jQuery AJAX transport plugins (including the ones linked in another answer here).

And, of course, XDomainRequest is subject to all of it's normal [limitations and constraints](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx). These aren't bugs per-se, and compared with the alernatives (iframe kludges, Flash crossdomain.xml transports) they're not **that** bad.

I've posted a new jQuery AJAX XDomainRequest transport under a public domain license here: https://github.com/ebickle/snippets/tree/master/javascript/xdomainrequest

Comment: This is a great answer that has strangely gone unnoticed.

Comment: You can not imagine how you help me. Great thx! I become mad, while trying to fix this bug.

Comment: This is the best answer by far

Comment: Late to the party, but would putting `var dummy = xdr` in onload/onerror solve xdr from being GC'd until completion? This would save the need for a global.

Answer (score 11):

Had the exact same question. Short solution:

1. Use this code: https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/ajax/xdr.js

UPDATE: link is broken, find jaubourgs fix here: https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/xdr.js

2. Add `xdr.onprogress = function() {};` in that xdr.js file

Details can be found on the jQuery topic discussion here

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283

in which the last reply included that xdr.onprogress fix which originated from this bug discussion which was aptly titled

"IE9 RTM - XDomainRequest issued requests may abort if all event handlers not specified"
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/30ef3add-767c-4436-b8a9-f1ca19b4812e

Comment: Thanks so much. This answer saved me possibly days of work. Internet Explorer is going to be the death of me.