# How to set header Access-Control-Allow-Origin for XDomain

Tags: java, javascript

How to set header Access-Control-Allow-Origin for XDomain

i am trying to do this by java code or by script code.

Please suggest me some way.

Comment: What are you trying to access? The headers are set by the server most of the time, unless you are processing the request by code.

Comment: i am trying to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739384/xdomainrequest-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](http://enable-cors.org/) all the information you need to enable CORS.

The easiest way to do it is by creating an `.htaccess` file inside the directory that you want to serve with the headers with this line:

> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

In the link above, you can find plenty other methods. I'm sure some of them should suit you.

Comment: You should mention that this is an Apache-only solution. As Java is mentioned the web server may be a Tomcat or something else.